# JScrollBar is not working

Tags: java, user-interface, jscrollpane

I'm trying to add a `JScrollPane` to `JTextArea`, but when I add it, `JPane` is not showing my `textarea` anymore. Without `JScrollPane` it shows it, but then I can't display all the information retrieved from a file.

This is my code for one of `textArea`s which I want to be wrapped with `JScrollPane`.

```
   public GUI_CWK()
{
    //frame details
    setSize(450,400);

    setLayout(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("H.o. | Location Database");
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    // Useing Lable to set a title for multiple buttons
    lbl2 = new JLabel();
    lbl2.setSize(420,85);
    lbl2.setLocation(15,0);
    lbl2.setEnabled(false);
    lbl2.setFont(new Font ("arial",5,17));
    lbl2.setText("Options to Manipulate with Data");
    add(lbl2);

    // Adding buttons to JFrame
    btn1 = new JButton("Add new entry");
    btn1.setSize(120,20);
    btn1.setLocation(7,80);
    btn1.addActionListener(this);
    add(btn1);

    btn2 = new JButton("Search");
    btn2.setSize(120,20);
    btn2.setLocation(7,110);
    btn2.addActionListener(this);
    add(btn2);

    btn3 = new JButton("Update Entry");
    btn3.setSize(120,20);
    btn3.setLocation(150,110);
    btn3.addActionListener(this);
    add(btn3);

    btn4 = new JButton("Print All");
    btn4.setSize(120,20);
    btn4.setLocation(150,80);
    btn4.addActionListener(this);
    add(btn4);

    btn5 = new JButton("Print Arrays");
    btn5.setSize(120,20);
    btn5.setLocation(7,140);
    btn5.addActionListener(this);
    add(btn5);

    btn6 = new JButton("Delete Entry");
    btn6.setSize(120,20);
    btn6.setLocation(300,80);
    btn6.addActionListener(this);
    add(btn6);

    btn7 = new JButton("Delete ALL");
    btn7.setSize(120,20);
    btn7.setLocation(300,110);
    btn7.addActionListener(this);
    add(btn7);

    lbl1 = new JLabel();
    lbl1.setSize(420,85);
    lbl1.setLocation(15,190);
    lbl1.setEnabled(false);
    lbl1.setFont(new Font ("arial",5,17));
    lbl1.setText("Extra Options");
    add(lbl1);

    btn8 = new JButton("Sort Data");
    btn8.setSize(160,20);
    btn8.setLocation(7,265);
    btn8.addActionListener(this);
    add(btn8);

    btn9 = new JButton("Open Text file");
    btn9.setSize(160,20);
    btn9.setLocation(7,300);
    btn9.addActionListener(this);
    add(btn9);

    btn11 = new JButton("Retrieve from text file");
    btn11.setSize(160,20);
    btn11.setLocation(240,265);
    btn11.addActionListener(this);
    add(btn11);

    btn12 = new JButton("Exit Program");
    btn12.setSize(160,20);
    btn12.setLocation(240,300);
    btn12.addActionListener(this);
    add(btn12);

    lbl3 = new JLabel();
    lbl3.setSize(420,85);
    lbl3.setLocation(15,340);
    lbl3.setEnabled(false);
    lbl3.setFont(new Font ("arial",5,17));
    lbl3.setText("Terminal Window");
    add(lbl3);
    // Adding textArea to display each user entered value
    textArea2 = new JTextArea(5, 20);
    textArea2.setEditable(false);
    textArea2.setSize(440,300);
    textArea2.setLocation(7,400);
    textArea2.setDisabledTextColor(Color.black);
    textArea2.setFont(new Font("arial",5,14));
    sp2 = new JScrollPane(textArea2);
    sp2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy ( ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS );
    add(sp2);

    lbl4 = new JLabel();
    lbl4.setSize(420,40);
    lbl4.setLocation(570,10);
    lbl4.setEnabled(false);
    lbl4.setFont(new Font ("arial",5,17));
    lbl4.setText("Data Display");
    add(lbl4);

    textArea = new JTextArea(55, 50);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setSize(800,640);
    textArea.setLocation(560,60);
    textArea.setFont(new Font("arial",5,19));
    textArea.setDisabledTextColor(Color.black);
    sp = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy ( ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS );
    add(sp);

    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the entire code of your program?

Comment: Code for all my program is nearly 600 lines long. I don't think you want to go thru it all. If you could specify what exactly you need more from my code to understand the problem, please.

Comment: I'd like to see how you are adding your `JComponents` to your `JFrame`, so I can see if I can solve the problem. Sorry for not being specific.

Comment: You have to add your `JComponent`s to a `JPane` and then add the last one to a `JFrame` (in case you don't know, what I think you do. Just in case).

Comment: I edited my code, Now there is everything from the constructor.

Comment: Why are you setting the size and location of your text area? That should be taken care of by your layout manager.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that in my code are a lot of mistakes, this is my first GUI project and that is the reason why I'm struggling a lot with parts which are simple for others.

Comment: I think that I already know what the problem Is. I'll post an answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: And I have no idea how to set size and location in different way Matt. Most  of the codes are just found in internet.

Comment: I suspect that you should set your scroll pane min/max/preferred sizes other wise your layout  manager will not give it enough space to be visible.

Comment: The way you are setting the size and location doesn't do anything as far as I know, because the layout manager will change it.

Comment: One more thing, if you use @ with the user name, it will let the user know that you responded.

Comment: @matt I do not actually know why, but in this way I can change the size and location in my program. But as soon as I add a command to wrap the ScrollPane in the same size like textArea, whole textArea disappears when I run the program. I really do not know any other way how to make components in constructor. :(

Comment: The text area has a size determined by the columns and rows that you pass the constructor. The scroll pane doesn't have a size, you need to let your layout manager handle that. Where you add the scroll pane call "sp.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(height, width)` youll have to choose the height and width. Also use `setPreferredSize` and `setMaximumSize`. These aren't strictly necessary, but it gives a hint for your layout manager about the size you want the scroll pane. Also, can you add an image of what you get w/out the scroll pane so we can recommend a layout?

Comment: @matt The thing is that I am creating my own layout and that's why I have problems with adding components.

Comment: Then set the size of your scroll pane, not the text area.

Comment: eg. instead of `textArea2.setSize(440,300);' use `sp2.setSize(440, 300);` and instead of `textArea2.setLocation(7,400);` use `sp2.setLocation(7, 400);`

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should solve your problem.

You'll notice that I erased the `this`s between the `addActionListener()` methods because you have to specify what do you want the `ActionListener`s to do.

`StartingPoint` (main) class:

```
public class StartingPoint{
public static void main(String[] args){

    GUI_CWK gui_cwk = new GUI_CWK(); //Creates a new instance of "GUI_CWK".
    gui_cwk.setVisible(true); //You set the gui_cwk to visible.

}
}
```

`GUI_CWK` class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

public class GUI_CWK extends JFrame{ 
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public GUI_CWK() {

    // frame details
    this.setSize(450, 400);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    this.setLayout(null); /* Each time that you want to refer to the classyou are in, you say "this" */
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("H.o. | Location Database");
    this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

    // Using labels to set a title for multiple buttons
    JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel(); /*Remember that you have to create the instances of an object by naming the class before the name of the instance */
    lbl2.setSize(420, 85);
    lbl2.setLocation(15, 0);
    lbl2.setEnabled(false);
    lbl2.setFont(new Font("arial", 5, 17));
    lbl2.setText("Options to Manipulate with Data");
    panel.add(lbl2);

    // Adding buttons to JFrame
    JButton btn1 = new JButton("Add new entry");
    btn1.setSize(120, 20);
    btn1.setLocation(7, 80);
    btn1.addActionListener(/* Insert ActionListener */);
    panel.add(btn1); //The button is added to the panel, so then the last one can be added to the JFrame at the end.

    JButton btn2 = new JButton("Search");
    btn2.setSize(120, 20);
    btn2.setLocation(7, 110);
    btn2.addActionListener(/* Insert ActionListener */);
    panel.add(btn2);

    JButton btn3 = new JButton("Update Entry");
    btn3.setSize(120, 20);
    btn3.setLocation(150, 110);
    btn3.addActionListener(/* Insert ActionListener */);
    panel.add(btn3);

    JButton btn4 = new JButton("Print All");
    btn4.setSize(120, 20);
    btn4.setLocation(150, 80);
    btn4.addActionListener(/* Insert ActionListener */);
    panel.add(btn4);

    JButton btn5 = new JButton("Print Arrays");
    btn5.setSize(120, 20);
    btn5.setLocation(7, 140);
    btn5.addActionListener(/* Insert ActionListener */);
    panel.add(btn5);

    JButton btn6 = new JButton("Delete Entry");
    btn6.setSize(120, 20);
    btn6.setLocation(300, 80);
    btn6.addActionListener(/* Insert ActionListener */);
    panel.add(btn6);

    JButton btn7 = new JButton("Delete ALL");
    btn7.setSize(120, 20);
    btn7.setLocation(300, 110);
    btn7.addActionListener(/* Insert ActionListener */);
    panel.add(btn7);

    JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel();
    lbl1.setSize(420, 85);
    lbl1.setLocation(15, 190);
    lbl1.setEnabled(false);
    lbl1.setFont(new Font("arial", 5, 17));
    lbl1.setText("Extra Options");
    panel.add(lbl1);

    JButton btn8 = new JButton("Sort Data");
    btn8.setSize(160, 20);
    btn8.setLocation(7, 265);
    btn8.addActionListener(/* Insert ActionListener */);
    panel.add(btn8);

    JButton btn9 = new JButton("Open Text file");
    btn9.setSize(160, 20);
    btn9.setLocation(7, 300);
    btn9.addActionListener(/* Insert ActionListener */);
    panel.add(btn9);

    JButton btn11 = new JButton("Retrieve from text file");
    btn11.setSize(160, 20);
    btn11.setLocation(240, 265);
    btn11.addActionListener(/* Insert ActionListener */);
    panel.add(btn11);

    JButton btn12 = new JButton("Exit Program");
    btn12.setSize(160, 20);
    btn12.setLocation(240, 300);
    btn12.addActionListener(/* Insert ActionListener */);
    panel.add(btn12);

    JLabel lbl3 = new JLabel();
    lbl3.setSize(420, 85);
    lbl3.setLocation(15, 340);
    lbl3.setEnabled(false);
    lbl3.setFont(new Font("arial", 5, 17));
    lbl3.setText("Terminal Window");
    panel.add(lbl3);

    // Adding textArea to display each user entered value
    JTextArea textArea2 = new JTextArea(5, 20);
    textArea2.setEditable(false);
    textArea2.setSize(440, 300);
    textArea2.setLocation(7, 400);
    textArea2.setDisabledTextColor(Color.black);
    textArea2.setFont(new Font("arial", 5, 14));

    JScrollPane sp2 = new JScrollPane(textArea2);
    sp2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    textArea2.add(sp2); //Here you add the scrollPanel to the textArea,
                        //in the original code you were adding it to the frame
    panel.add(textArea2);

    JLabel lbl4 = new JLabel();
    lbl4.setSize(420, 40);
    lbl4.setLocation(570, 10);
    lbl4.setEnabled(false);
    lbl4.setFont(new Font("arial", 5, 17));
    lbl4.setText("Data Display");
    panel.add(lbl4);

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(55, 50);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setSize(800, 640);
    textArea.setLocation(560, 60);
    textArea.setFont(new Font("arial", 5, 19));
    textArea.setDisabledTextColor(Color.black);
    JScrollPane sp1 = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    sp1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    textArea.setVisible(true);
    textArea.add(sp1);
    panel.add(textArea);

    this.add(panel); //Everything which was added to the panel now is added to the frame.
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

Comment: You should explain the change you made a little bit. You also shouldn't call your class Window.

Comment: For an ActionListener I created a new method called actionPerformed where i check with if statements... if (e.getSource() == btn3) {
            try{
                Update();
            }catch (NullPointerException ex){}

What do you think? Is it good to catch actions like this or I should change it?

Comment: @explodedBaloon Actually, I never tried to use ActionListener in that way. Try it. I'll try it to; and if it works, I'll update the answer's code again.

Comment: @explodedBaloon I just searched for information about the use of `swich()` with `ActionEvent` and figured out that you can't use the first one with the last between it's parentheses.
Now, I wanted to try what you said by leaving the `public GUI_CWK(){};`constructor empty at the top, and the rest of the code below; so I can refer to the ActionListener with `this`, but I have an error with the `GUI_CWK` constructor.
Try to do the same and tell me if you have the same problem.

Comment: @JavaNoob I did it like this - btn12.addActionListener(this); and then in new method called ActionPerformed I placed an if statement which i showed before and it works for me. When I click a button it gets the action and things are happening,

Comment: When you are saying "new method" what are you refering to?

This is what I get: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BSOhQ.png

Comment: Ooooh... So you put all the code in just one class. That's why you don't have any problems. Thanks.

As my answer solved your problem, could you upvote it?

Comment: @JavaNoob Sorry, but I tried as much as I can to implement your solution, but it is not working for me. Also my rating is less than 15 that's why if will upvote, it will not show it. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using a scroll pane.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class ScrollPaneExample{
    public void buildGui(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("button and scrollpane");

        JButton button = new JButton("example");
        JTextArea area = new JTextArea(20, 20);
        //this is where we will place our components.
        //It has a flow layout by default.
        JPanel content = new JPanel(); 

        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(area);
        content.add(button);
        content.add(sp);

        //this line limits the size of the scroll pane.
        sp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 60));

        //The frame will use our panel instead of the default one.
        frame.setContentPane(content);

        //sizes the frame to the content area.
        frame.pack();        

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(()->{new ScrollPaneExample().buildGui();});
    }

}
```

The main difference is that I set my content pane so I know its layout manager. You appear to be manually setting all of the sizes, which I am surprised it works. You should choose a good layout manager. [pick one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) you think does what you want.

Also note that this is a minimal example that will compile.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for help guys, I found out the answer. As @matt told me, I should add size and location to JScrollPane instead of textArea. So I did it and it works for me now.

code is below.

---

```
 textArea2 = new JTextArea(5,20);
    textArea2.setEditable(false);
    textArea2.setDisabledTextColor(Color.black);
    textArea2.setFont(new Font("arial",5,14));
    sp2 = new JScrollPane(textArea2);
    sp2.setSize(440,300);
    sp2.setLocation(7,400);
    sp2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy ( ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS );
    add(sp2);
```